# Помогите с фибоначи и лямбдой

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Нужно заполнить дек числами фибоначи при помощи алгоритма generate и лямбда функции.Может кто подкинет идейку через анонимную лямбду?А то через просто функцию сам догадываюсь

Comment: лямбда - та же функция, за исключением того, что пишется прямо на месте и не требует объявления. Так что если догадываетесь как это сделать через функцию, то с лямбдой то же самое.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch догадываюсь через рекурсионную обычную функцию.Через анонимку без понятия.Переменная статическая разве-что

Comment: организуйте цикл - практически все, что можно делается через рекурсию можно сделать циклами.

Comment: Написал. Удалил :) - напишите, как вы это сделаете с помощью функции - восстанавливаю свой ответ. Просто чтоб было понятно, что не делаю все полностью за вас...

Comment: @Harry дык не писал ещё ничего.Знаю что есть рекурсионная формула f(n-1)+f(n-2)

Comment: @Harry Формула Бине и всё) в лямбду идеально

Comment: @pavel Ну... не думаю, не думаю. Смысла нет. Рекурсивно проще.

Comment: Ладно, просто некогда отслеживать, что вы напишете... Восстанавливаю ответ, только просьба - вы уж хотя бы разберитесь, как оно работает, перед тем как сдавать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то типа

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    deque<int> fib;
    generate_n(back_inserter(fib),40,[](){static int f0 = 0, f1 = 1; 
                                          int save = f0; f0 = f1; 
                                          f1 += save; return save; });

    for(auto i: fib) cout << i << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Элегантнее, наверное, все-таки через изменяемую лямбду:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto f = [x0 = 0u, x1 = 1u]() mutable -> unsigned { auto retVal = x0; x0 = x1; x1 = retVal + x0; return retVal; };
    std::cout << f() << '\n';
    std::cout << f() << '\n';
    std::cout << f() << '\n';
    std::cout << f() << '\n';
    std::cout << f() << '\n';
    std::cout << f() << '\n';
}
```